# Skip input prompt if help passed to click for subcommand

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-click

I have a simple Python click program, where I am trying to skip input for two optional parameters if someone issues `--help` on a subcommand:

```
import click


@click.group()
@click.option("--user", envvar="PKGPUSH_USER", prompt="user", help="user to auth with")
@click.option("--password", envvar="PKGPUSH_PASSWORD", prompt="password", hide_input=True, help="password to auth with")
@click.pass_context
def cli(ctx, user, password):
    ctx.ensure_object(dict)
    ctx.obj["user"] = user
    ctx.obj["password"] = password

@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def deb(ctx):
    """Push .deb packages to repo"""
    pass

@cli.command()
@click.pass_context
def rpm(ctx):
    """Push .rpm packages to repo."""
    click.echo(f"{ctx.obj['user']} | {ctx.obj['password']}")


if __name__ == "__main__":
    cli()
```

Right now, if I issue `pkgpush rpm --help` it will prompt me for the `user` and `password` options on `cli()`. I can't use `prompt_required=False` either, as it seems to make it so it will never prompt if `--help` *isn't* passed which in that case I would want it to.

The desired behavior is that when `--help` is passed to a subcommand, it skips any options on `cli()` and provides help output for the subcommand, but if `--help` isn't provided I want it to prompt if they don't explicitly pass the `--user` and/or `--password` option or set the ENVVAR specified. Is there a way to make click recognize that `--help` has been passed to a subcommand and skip those prompts if that is the case?

Answer (score 0):

There is a way to do this, although a bit weird and may be error prone:

```py
class ConditionalPrompt(click.Group):
    def parse_args(self, ctx, args):
        if ('--help') in args:
            for param in ctx.command.params:
                param.prompt = None
        super().parse_args(ctx, args)

@click.group(cls=ConditionalPrompt)
```

What it does:

1. We create custom Group class
2. We override the parse_args method, searching for help arguments
3. If there is such, we suppress the prompt of **all** group options
4. We call the original parse_args method to get the job done

You could customise further in a way that:

1. you are handling help aliases, using `get_help_option_names`
2. Change only those options, you need to.